# Unit testing class with private constructor created from factory method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I know very similar questions have been asked/answered, but I have a somewhat peculiar scenario that I can't resolve.

We are creating a library for use in other applications, and this library is centered around a main library class that the user instantiates and works with.  This class has a variety of dependencies, and part of the design requirements dictate that we do not want the users of the library to deal with creating the dependency object graph or deal with initialization tasks, so we have made the class constructor private, and have them create an instance from a static method, which in turn creates an instance of the class and resolves the dependencies using an IoC container.  Something like this:

```
    public static ILibrary CreateInstance()
    {

        Library lib = new Library(
            IoC.Instance.Resolve<IDependency1>(),
            IoC.Instance.Resolve<IDependency2>(),
            // etc
            );

        lib.Initialize();

        return lib;
    }

    private Library(IDependency1, IDependency2, etc)
    {
        // some ctor setup here
    }
```

The core problem with testing this is the CreateInstance() method is calling the static instance of the IoC container to handle the dependency resolution, which prevents us from injecting our mock dependencies into the object graph.

In the spirit of "if you can't figure out how to test it, you probably have a design flaw", I'm wondering if someone could point out the correct way to approach this.

Comment: Top of my head: create an internal constructor, give your unit testing project access to internals via the "InternalsVisibleTo" (double check that name) attribute. Do a search on that approach if it interests you.

Comment: Where are you defining how your dependencies are resolved?

Comment: @IanP The IoC class has a static constructor which calls a private Initialize() method in which we register our dependencies.

Comment: Hmm. So are they defined in code or in something like a dependencies.config file?

Comment: I'll just cut to the chase :) If you're defining dependencies in a configuration file, would it be possible to use a different configuration when testing?

Comment: @IanP They are not in a config, they are in code, in an initialization method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

---

**`public` Constructor**

You mentioned that you don't want users of your library to have to deal with initialization, and creation of the object graph. That's a good reason to hide such initialization things behind a factory - but that doesn't preclude you from *allowing* users to deal with these details.

**Your tests can be seen as consumers of your code.** If a test would like the ability to configure an object a certain way (e.g., via dependency injection), then it's likely that other consumers would share this interest.

By providing a factory method, you give consumers *the ability to create the library without having to worry* about composing its object graph.

By providing a `public` constructor, you give consumers *the option* to create the library using a specific object graph.

---

**`internal` Constructor**

One approach that is commonly used for testing private components of shared libraries is to [expose relevant components specifically to the test project](http://bradfitzwater.com/2013/05/29/unit-testing-with-internalsvisibleto/).

Instead of specifying the constructor as `private`, mark it instead as `internal`. Then, modify the `AssemblyInfo` for your shared library to include the following assembly attribute:

```
    [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLibraryTestProject")]
```

Classes and methods marked as `internal` are normally only visible to the project in which they're defined. The above changes explicitly allow your test project to see (and test) them.

Comment: This (internal) is the approach I use for testing helper classes that are not externally visible, and it seems to be a straightforward approach for testing in this scenario, as well.

Comment: Ah, I had tried this based on @user414076 comment, but could not make it work, because I had not changed private to internal.  This might be the way to go, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I came up with, which works but is not completely ideal.  I would still be curious to hear other ideas.

In the factory method, instead of calling the static IoC.Instance,  I created a static property on the library itself, which returns the library's IoC container if it is not set, or allows me to override it with a container full of mocks.  Basically:

```
private static Container _container;
public static Container Container
{
    get { if (_container ==null) return IoC.Instance; return _container; }
    set { _container = value; }
}
```

So then in the unit test I just swap the container with the one for testing.

The only thing I don't like about this is that it is exposing a public property that I don't wish the library consumers to use, which muddies the API design a bit.  But it's possible I'm just picking nits at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To point in initializing the Library like this:

```
    Library lib = new Library(
        IoC.Instance.Resolve<IDependency1>(),
        IoC.Instance.Resolve<IDependency2>(),
        // etc
        );
```

Is that dependency injection in enable you to get your test dependency in there. Configure you IoC object to give the right dependency. It seems that you have to make a Mock IoC object when testen, using it to inject the test dependencies. You can make this easier by using a Mocking Framework, like Fakes, Mock, etc.